# Is there a way to select all option values in selectbox?

Tags: javascript, select, underscore.js, html-select

I have a function that creates many select boxes. I need an option value to select all the values in one select, because if I give "all" as value, I have to do a lot of switches and if / else statements, and it would be great if I could avoid that.
Here is the function:

```
function creaselect(nomeoggetto, oggetto, nome) {

var P_P_comodo = _(A_Punti_dati).groupBy(oggetto).map(function(item, itemId) {
    console.log(oggetto);

    var result = {};
    result[itemId] = item[0][nome];
    return result
}).value();

document.write("Seleziona " + nomeoggetto + "<select id=my" + nomeoggetto + ">");
document.write("<option value=all selected>Tutti</option>");
_.each(P_P_comodo, function(value, key) {
    _.each(value, function(value, key) {
        P_P[key] = value;
        document.write("<option value=" + key + ">" + value + "</option>");

    });

});
document.write("</select><br>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do 2 things:

1. Set up a function to iterate through each option and set the "selected" attribute to true
2. Set up a handler to call this function when the user selects "all"

#### HTML

```
    <select id='control'>
      <option value=''>(Select one)</option>
      <option value='all'>All</option>
      <option value='none'>None</option>
    </select>
    <select id='sel' name="sometext" size='5' multiple>
      <option value='1'>text1</option>
      <option value='2'>text2</option>
      <option value='3'>text3</option>
      <option value='4'>text4</option>
      <option value='5'>text5</option>
    </select>
```

#### Javascript

```
    var control = document.getElementById('control');
    control.onchange = setOptions;
    function setOptions() {
      var control = document.getElementById('control');
      var val = control.value;
      if (val == 'all' || val == 'none') {
        var mySelectObj = document.getElementById('sel');
        var bool = val == 'all'
        setSelect(mySelectObj, bool);
      }  
    }

    function setSelect(sel, bool){
      for(var i = 0; i <sel.length; i++) {
        sel.options[i].selected = bool;
      }
    }
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/qqp7w1qk/11/

**Please note:** *in order to allow multi-select on a select input, you must specify the attribute "multiple". Otherwise, you'll need to use a third-party select control.*

Comment: Sorry, was pointing to an old version of my jsFiddle. I have updated.

Comment: Very nice. This was just a quick code gen to illustrate the concept. I'm sure your implementation will be much different than my example.

Comment: No, feel free to use it and modify in answer if you want